# How to use systemd notify

Tags: systemd, notification

I'm learning how to use systemd notify. I'm thinking it is a kind of mechanism, which allows a process to send a notification to another process.

So, I tried to make a notification with the command `systemd-notify --ready --status="hello"`. Then I got an error: `No status data could be sent: $NOTIFY_SOCKET was not set`. It seems that it needs a listener, just like the socket. But I don't know how to make a listener to receive this notification.

Also, I've known that the service of systemd has some different types, one of them is `notify`. The doc said, `Type=notify: identical to Type=simple, but with the stipulation that the daemon will send a signal to systemd when it is ready.`. So it seems that the service whose type is notify can send notification too, but I don't know how to use it either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `systemd-notify` tool is specifically meant to be used by a shell that runs as a systemd service using `Type=notify`.

If you set up a service using `Type=notify`, systemd will automatically set up a communication socket back to systemd and will export its path to the service under `$NOTIFY_SOCKET`.

It will also listen for special messages in that socket, such as whether the service is ready (in which case systemd will transition it to status `started`, since initialization is completed) and also the self-reported status of the service, which will also be reported in the output of `systemctl status mytest.service` (assuming a service called `mytest`.)

You can read the [man page of `systemd-notify`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-notify.html) for all the details, even though there's a lot of complexity there... Perhaps the example at the end is useful in illustrating how it works.

---

Let's use that example for a hands-on experiment!

Create a script like the one below somewhere in your system, such as `/usr/local/bin/mytest.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo /tmp/waldo
sleep 10
systemd-notify --ready --status="Waiting for data…"

while : ; do
        read a < /tmp/waldo
        systemd-notify --status="Processing $a"

        # Do something with $a …
        sleep 10

        systemd-notify --status="Waiting for data…"
done
```

I added some `sleep 10`s so you can see what's happen, when watching the `systemctl status mytest.service` output.

Make the script executable:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mytest.sh
```

Then create `/etc/systemd/system/mytest.service`, with contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Test

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mytest.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then reload systemd (so it learns about the unit) and start it:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl start mytest.service
```

Then watch status output, every so often:

```
$ systemctl status mytest.service
```

You'll see it's `starting` for the first 10 seconds, after which it will be `started` and its status will be "Waiting for data…".

Now write some data into the FIFO (you'll need to use `tee` to run it as root):

```
$ echo somedata | sudo tee /tmp/waldo
```

And watch the status:

```
$ systemctl status mytest.service
```

It will show the status of the service as "Processing somedata" for 10 seconds, then back to "Waiting for data…".

If you were to write this code in C or another language that supports systemd bindings, you would use the `sd_notify()` function for this purpose. If you're familiar with C, you might want to take a look at the [sd_notify(3)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html#) man page.

Comment: So, `systemd-notify` has to work with `fifo` file? I mean, we, the users, have to offer a way of communication so that `systemd-notify` could work? I thought `systemd-notify` have had some method to build its own way of communication...

Comment: @yves No, the `fifo` has nothing to do with `systemd-notify`. Filbranden just used it here for the example script to _tickle_ the script somehow from another window.

Comment: Yeah the `/tmp/waldo` fifo is just a very very simple server to illustrate an example. My initial idea of an example was a counter script (set status to `$i`, increment `i`, sleep a second, loop.) You can try that too. `systemd-notify` wants to find the *socket* back to systemd and that's what gets exported (by systemd) in `$NOTIFY_SOCKET`, but that's mainly an implementation detail between two parts of systemd itself... I hope that helps you make sense of `Type=notify` and its uses, that's what this is all about.

Comment: It may be necessary to set `NotifyAccess=all` in the service unit if systemd-notify has not sufficient privileges to pretend having the PID of the invoking process (e.g. due to systemd security setting `RestrictNamespaces=yes`).

Answer (score 4):

To learn the message format sd_notify, you can try this:

terminal 1:

```
$ socat unix-recv:/tmp/test.sock -
```

terminal 2:

```
$ NOTIFY_SOCKET=/tmp/test.sock systemd-notify --ready --status="hello"
```

You will see result in terminal 1:

```
READY=1
STATUS=hello
```

Comment: Oh, now that's a simple protocol that even I can understand!

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but I got as far as this, using "netcat"

A) in one terminal session, do:

```
export NOTIFY_SOCKET=/tmp/test.sock
nc -l -U -u /tmp/test.sock
```

B) open another terminal session and do:

```
export NOTIFY_SOCKET=/tmp/test.sock
systemd-notify --read --status="hello"`
```

This works, but on the `netcat` side you will get `nc: connect: Invalid argument`. I don't know how to work around that.

Comment: How did you create the file `/tmp/test.sock`?

Comment: I didn't. It gets created as required.

Comment: Is it because `systems-notify` is using `SOCK_DGRAM` but `nc` is using `SOCK_STREAM`?